# Will optimal point of a convex function $f(x)$ under linear constraint lie on boundary?

Tags: convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I have a function $f(x)$ that is positive definite quadratic function. I have linear constraints , then will the optimal lie on boundary ?

My answer that I feel is "No" it will not lay at the boundary. But I am unable to give a solid proof due to my weak calculus. (specially when it comes to higher dimensions)

Can anyone help me visualize from $1$ dimension (taking $f(x)=x^2$) and move towards higher dimension ?

Comment: What do you mean by the boundary? Do you mean on the boundary of the set of points satisfying your linear constraint? There are definitely situations where the optimizer *does* occur on the boundary of the constraint set. However, to answer that question with "no," all you need is a counterexample.

Comment: The only linear subspaces in 1-D are $\{0\}$ and $\mathbb{R}$. If you're minimizing $x^2$ subject to $x\in\{0\}$ then clearly the solution will occur at the boundary. It won't happen if you're minimizing subject to $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: By boundary , I meant active constraint. Like one of the inequality will surely hold.

Comment: Ok, perhaps the question should specify that you mean **linear inequality constraints**. Frequently a "linear constraint" is requiring that $x$ resides in a vector subspace, i.e. a linear set. Linear inequality constraints are more general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might lie on the boundary though it need not.

Let's consider a one dimensional example.

$\min x^2$ subject to $x \ge 0$.

The optimal solution is clearly $x=0$ which is on the boundary.

$\min x^2$ subject to $x \ge -1$.

Then the optimal solution is not on the boundary.

In general, given $x^TAx+b^Tx$, differentiating it gives us $2Ax+b$, we can check if the stationary point is in the interior. Suppose not, then the optimal solution must be on the boundary.

Comment: The constraint $x\geq 0$ is nonlinear.

Comment: @Zim  The constraint $x \geq 0$ is a linear inequality constraint.  In your question, are you asking about linear equality constraints $a^{T}x=b$?

Comment: I was asking exactly what you answered. 
x>0 is linear inequality constraint. In case of equality if will surely lie on boundary so that is not a problem.

Comment: @Brian $C=\{x \, | \, x\geq 0\}$ is only a cone, not a linear set (e.g. 1 and 2 are in $C$ but the linear combination $1-2\not\in C$)... so the constraint $x\in C$ is nonlinear. Perhaps the question should have specified if considering linear *inequality* constraints.